# YouTube Default Player Event when playback over

Tags: events, youtube, playback

Does the normal YouTube player (by normal I mean the one you get when you use the embed code `iframe`) fire an event when playback is completed that I can catch outside the `iframe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As normal cross-domain javascript communication is restricted for security reasons this is not 'normally' possible.
In modern, HTML5 compliant, browsers a new method was introduced: `postMessage`. To be able to do exactly that: safe cross-domain communication in Javascript.

The `iframe` YouTube player 'posts' out an `onStateChanged` event with different stati. To enable this interaction however, you need to use Javascript to embed the `iframe` player.

Check out the following link to see how it's done.
(Experimental feature by the way...)

http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/youtube/iframe_api_reference.html